# Xtrareports stylesheet is missing

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, asp.net-core-3.1, devexpress-mvc

I'm using .NET CORE 3.1 and I implemented xtrareports in my project. Now I'm using free trial of Devexpress. But when I'm loading my project after publish project and publish node_modules file on server the *.repx is empty and I have 28 wrong for loading file . and the stylesheet file message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()".[image]

Comment: According to the error message on the console, your jquery file has not been loaded. Check your correct path. Can you also show the relevant code?

Comment: Thank you for interested. Yes in the beginning the node_modules after publish was empty. And I was loaded its Files but it don't work. I move this file to wwwroot but it was not success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nodeJS is installed on your server, IIS creates a virtual directory for node_modules and doesn't allow to serve this folder to client. So, even you upload the folder under wwwroot, client can not access this folder and report will not work.

So, try to remove virtual directory or move your files to another server that NodeJs is not installed.